# Is it practical to use List.Find to return class members of type?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm trying to get public variables from classes that are stored in a list.

The order of the list is random.

These classes all inherit a base class which is what the list is made from.

Since the order is random I have to search each list element to find the index belonging to the class I want. This is my solution

```
public List<behaviour> behaviours;
public Foo GetFoo { get { return (Foo)behaviours.Find( x => x is Foo ); } }
public Bar GetBar { get { return (Bar)behaviours.Find( x => x is Bar ); } }
public Foobar GetFoobar { get { return (Foobar)behaviours.Find( x => x is Foobar ); } }

GetFoobar.member = "hello world";
```

This works, but I'm looking for criticism because I don't think it's very intuitive. I think a better programmer wouldn't find themselves in this predicament.

Comment: How many of each type do you have? If only one of each, why not a property/field per class

Comment: At the moment there are 3 but I anticipate adding more in future when I introduce new mechanics

Comment: No how many of **each** type do you have? Currently you only return one per type

Comment: Just the one. I don't multiple instances of `Foo` in behaviours for example, unless I'm still misunderstanding you.

Comment: So you don't want a list at all. Just separate fields/properties for each one. If there is a part of the code that needs to see all of them then have an `IEnumerable<behaviour>` which aggregates them

Comment: This isn't polymorphism;it's bypassing it and is more like a classic "if shape is Triangle DrawTriangle() else if shape is Circle..." - Find a way to treat your classes in a base sense and expose the abstract of the functionality on the base then override it in the subclasses; treat them as a base but the specialized behavior per class is exhibited.. eg `shape.DrawYourselfOnThisCanvas(c)` - base class has DrawYourself abstract, a triangle instance draws a triangle, circle a circle. Some other dev can do a plug-in that draws a star,a shape your code never knew existed.That's leveraging poly'ism

Comment: but this notion of your code knowing all the types you have and looking for an exact instance of an exact type and using it means it's relatively pointless to have a base class at all; treat the instances in the general sense of the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some base classes for the samples

```cs
    public class Base {
        public string Member { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo : Base { }
    public class Bar : Base { }
```

If you will only have 1 type of each in your base class, you can use a `Dictionary<Type, class>`.

```cs
    public class ViaTypeDict
    {
        private Dictionary<Type, Base> _behaviours = new Dictionary<Type, Base>() {
                {typeof(Foo), new Foo() },
                {typeof(Bar), new Bar()}
            };
        private T GetBehaviour<T>() where T : Base
        {
            return _behaviours.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out var result) ? result as T : null;
        }
        public List<Base> Behaviours => _behaviours.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        public Foo GetFoo { get { return GetBehaviour<Foo>(); } }
        public Bar GetBar { get { return GetBehaviour<Bar>(); } }
    }
```

If you will have multiple of the same type, you could use a `Dictionary<string, class>`;

```cs
    public class ViaStringDict
    {
        private Dictionary<string, Base> _behaviours = new Dictionary<string, Base>() {
                {nameof(GetFoo), new Foo() },
                {nameof(GetBar), new Bar()}
            };
        private T GetBehaviour<T>([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string memberName = null) where T : Base
        {
            return _behaviours.TryGetValue(memberName, out var result) ? result as T : null;
        }
        public List<Base> Behaviours => _behaviours.Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
        public Foo GetFoo { get { return GetBehaviour<Foo>(); } }
        public Bar GetBar { get { return GetBehaviour<Bar>(); } }
    }
```

I added the list sample, to show you how it could be done without `Find`. `OfType` gives you a find and type cast in 1 go.

```cs
    public class ViaList
    {
        public List<Base> Behaviours { get; } = new List<Base>() { new Foo(), new Bar() };
        public Foo GetFoo { get { return Behaviours.OfType<Foo>().FirstOrDefault(); } }
        public Bar GetBar { get { return Behaviours.OfType<Bar>().FirstOrDefault(); } }
    }
```

I added a sample where the list is based on your properties, instead of your properties based on your list.

```cs
    public class ListBasedOnProperties
    {
        public List<Base> Behaviours => new List<Base>() { GetFoo, GetBar };
        public Foo GetFoo { get; } = new Foo();
        public Bar GetBar { get; } = new Bar();
    }
```

All of them have the same issue, the list/dictionary needs to be populated with each property in order to work. If you don't mind this, go ahead. If you are going to have a lot of properties. Maybe change `public List<Base> Behaviours => new List<Base>() { GetFoo, GetBar };` to a list populated using reflection.